# Params Not In Rails Controller Method, but in before filter and application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have controllers that look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :print_params

  def print_params
   p params
  end
end

class CommandsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :print_params

  def print_params
   p params
  end
end

class FidelityBondRenewalsController < CommandsController
  before_filter :print_params

  def print_params
   p params
  end

  def renew_with_changes 
     p params
  end
end
```

When I run my cucumber tests I see print params the whole way through except for when I finally hit the renew_with_changes method and then my params disappear. I have other methods in this controller and it isn't happening to them. I've searched the code base for any differences between the other methods and this one and couldn't find anything.

If I put a binding.pry in the print_params method in the FidelityBondRenewalsController and hit next over and over again, I eventually get to:

```
    16: def process_action(*args)
    17:   run_callbacks(:process_action, action_name) do
 => 18:     super
    19:   end
    20: end
```

which has params. If I type next, then I go to my `renew_with_changes` method and the params are gone.

What can I try to try to track this down? This is a Rails3.2 app, with the strong parameters gem installed to be more like Rails4, if that is useful.

Route information:

```
  resources :fidelity_bond_renewals do
    member do
      .
      .
      .
      put :renew_with_changes
    end 
  end
```

Comment: This is a weird one. Is there anything strange going on in your route definitions?

Comment: @BenLee No, not really. This is a monolith app, so there is a lot going on in there, but if I look at renew_with_changes specifically it looks pretty normal. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What is `renew_with_changes` method? Is it a action mapped to any route in routes.rb ? Let me know first that

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, it is mapped to a route in routes.rb. I posted that above. You may have missed it, since it is such a recent posting. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Are there any other filters involved, specifically for `renew_with_changes`?

Comment: There are other before filters involved. They all apply to at least one other controller method that isn't affected by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was two fold:

1. For whatever reason Binding.pry could not read the params. I haven't figured out why. I could do `p params` and see them. I could do a `binding.pry` right after that and try to `p params` and they would not print. This is different behavior than I described above. The only change is that I am driving today and my pair is not. We may need to resolve these difference if we can reproduce them. I'll report back on this if he experiences differences.
2. The params themselves were being manipulated by some code that meant that I needed to access the key differently. Once this was figured out, it all started working.